# Surface Pro 3 Typecover is constantly breaking

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, hardware-failure, microsoft-surface-pro-3

Surface Pro 3 Typecover seems to stop responding for random amounts of time. This is getting really annoying because every time I try to use the typecover 7/10 times it breaks. Anyone know a permament fix? I currently have a temporary fix. That temporary fix involves turning the Surface Pro 3 off, and holding the power & volume-up button at the same time for 10 seconds. Although that doesn't do because when you have to do that at least 3 times a day, it gets stupid.

Comment: You should describe better how Typecover fails to work, and what is the temporary fix you are using?

Comment: I have edited the description to fit the criteria that you requested